# Running docker on Android

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, docker

With Android 4.4 KitKat, Google is upgrading linux kernel to version 3.8 which is the required kernel version for Docker.

I don't know the AUFS part but will there be a way to run docker containers on android with this update?

Comment: I was wondering the exact opposite, ie running Android inside Docker. If Chromebooks do it...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/kernel.html), the Android kernel is missing quite a few of [the kernel features needed by LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/man/lxc.html#AEN22).

Perhaps in the future with Docker 1.x, it might be possible to write a plugin that uses Android features instead of LXC. But for now, you would need to build a custom Android kernel and then build LXC for it.

There are [some](http://www.linuxplumbersconf.org/2013/ocw/sessions/975) [people](https://funnel.hasgeek.com/droidcon2013/889-lxc-on-android-running-ics-and-jellybean-simultane) actually working on that, and [Stéphane Graber has a good summary of the difficulties on his blog](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/23/lxc-1-0-some-more-advanced-container-usage/).

Comment: How about now that [Docker is going to be based on libcontainer](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/12/01/docker_part_2_the_libcontainer_evolution/)?

Comment: It's a different problem but similar. libcontainer likely needs some kernel features not available in Android. You'd have to try it and see what's needed.

Comment: what is the current state of this?

Comment: @strages There's no reason to believe the situation has changed much. Some people are reporting success with flashing a full Linux kernel onto an Android device: https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki/AndroidContainer.

Comment: @RohanSingh thanks for the answer, however as I asked about it on the repository. That is a very old and unmaintained content link. Are there no more recent ventures?

Comment: There is s new WIP evaluation on this: https://gist.github.com/arno01/ebf570af208e28c1a0cf78da4f63bc9c

Answer (score 6):

It depends if this kernel is compiled with the required features to run containers. If it's the case, then Docker could be used on Android (especially Docker 0.7, which is in release candidate state right now, and doesn't require AUFS anymore).