# dockerd Error on android : failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted

Tags: android, docker, systemd, systemctl, cgroups

I have installed ***docker on android x86_64*** virtual and ***docker --version works*** and shows me right version. but ***dockerd*** does not work and gives me " **failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted ".** i searched a lot but non of them worked so far. these are the problem I have, among solutions:

1- systemd does not exist on android(it seems, systemctl command not
    found). we can start docker by systemctl start docker in linux.

2- I cannot find grub file to modify it (as a few solutions says)

3- I don't know if cgroup is well installed on android? how to check it,
    needs again systemd!

The screen shot is attached

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like docker can't run on Android kernel at all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527277/is-it-possible-to-run-containers-on-android-devices

Comment: actually it is possible, i did it but i have some minor problems which couldn't fix yet. but I could pull from docker HUB and run the container well. thanks